# Get JavaScript calculator in degree mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, switch-statement, trigonometry

I'm working on getting my JavaScript calculator to perform calculations in degree mode by converting an input (in degrees) to radians (since the `Math.cos()` function only accepts radians). I use a button to switch between each mode in accordance with this code:

```
$('#button-mode').click(function() {

  var type = $(this).val(),
            $div = $('.mode');

        switch (type) {
        case 'DEG':
            $div.html('DEG');
            $('#button-mode').html('Rad');
            $('#button-mode').val('RAD');
            break;
        case 'RAD':
            $div.html('RAD');
            $('#button-mode').html('Deg');
            $('#button-mode').val('DEG');
            break;
                }
            });
```

Now, this merely changes the HTML of a div positioned in the input display so that the user knows what mode the calculator is in. I tried using a counter with this `#button-mode`and having the cosine button execute a different function (`cos` or `cosDeg` - below) depending on the click count of the mode button.

```
function cos(form) {
  form.display.value = Math.cos(form.display.value);
}

function cosDeg(form) {
  form.display.value = Math.cos(form.display.value*(Math.PI/180));
}
```

While something to that effect occurs, the `cosDeg` function does not seem to produce anywhere near the correct value. For example, if a user inout 180 and hits the cosine button, the return value is something like *-0.59846...* when it should return *-1*.

I've also tried to achieve the desired effect with this snippet, but it doesn't work at all, and I'm not sure why exactly:

```
$('#button-cos').click(function(){
    var argument = this.form.display.value;

if ($("#button-mode").html() == 'Rad') {
    var cosArg = Math.cos(argument);
setTimeout (function(){
    $("#disp").val('cosArg');
    },0.5);
}

else if ($("#button-mode").html() == 'Deg') {
    var argumentDEG = argument * (Math.PI/180);
    var cosArgDEG = Math.cos(argumentDEG );
setTimeout (function(){
    $("#disp").val('cosArgDEG');
    },0.5);
}
```

});

Clearly, I need help. How would I go about getting a button to control the mode and to get the correct return from the `cosDeg` function?

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code for starters.  `Math.cos((form.display.value*(Math.PI/180));` has one too many opening parenthesis.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Changed it and it still doesn't work properly.